# For a Matrix, what is a "Solution Vector"?

Tags: linear-algebra

If given a value $N$ and told to generate the following:

- A random matrix $A[N][N]$
- A solution vector $S[N]$

What would be a "solution vector" of a randomly generated matrix? I am not sure I have heard the term used before or I am simply mixing terms in my mind.

Comment: My hunch is that it S will either be the $x$ or the $b$ in the equation $Ax=b$. The word "solution" implies it may be more likely to be the $x$ You may be able to glean a little more information from the context it arises in.

Comment: @DavidReed So it would be appear that it would be the $x$; but can you derive $x$ upon generation of a random matrix?

Comment: It looks like they want you to use the same parameter to generate the x (viewing it as a 1 column matrix). You would not be able derive x without first having the b.

Comment: @DavidReed So mathematically you cannot solve for $x$ without having $b$ even though you have the matrix?

Comment: Yes, different values of b will give you different values of x

Comment: @DavidReed The problem set states to generate what is in the original post, then to multiply them to resolve $B[N]$. So if only given $N$, it is not possible to generate a both $A[N][N]$ and $S[N]$ without getting different values for $B[N]$?

Comment: I'm not familiar with what they mean by "resolve". It sounds like they want you to generate A and x and then multiply them to get b. b will in general be different when A or x is changed. If you could take a picture of the page and link it in a comment here I might be able to get a better idea.